# Is it really problem if 0,3 voltage more than required applied in digital multimeter?

Tags: multimeter, basic

Does it negatively affect if more 0,3v voltage than Power Supply (PS) required by general digital multimeter (DMM) supplied ?. I have a DMM with PS requirement of 2 x 1.5v AA battery and in hand is 2 x 1.65v battery. Can I just safely apply the 3.3 v into the 3v PS requirement of DMM which would be 10% extra power than should be ?

Comment: Did you measure the loaded voltage?

Comment: No, of course. I don't even have gut to apply the 2x1.65v to DMM at all !

Answer (score 4):

The batteries will be just fine in the multimeter.

Batteries are specified at a "nominal" voltage, they have a discharge curve so the terminal voltage varies throughout it's useful life.

Here is the datasheet for a [Duracell AA](http://professional.duracell.com/downloads//datasheets/product/Ultra%20Power/Ultra-Power_AA_MX1500.pdf) battery.
It's discharge characteristics show that it will be at 1.6 V when new, and the terminal voltage drops with both discharge rate and capacity used.

Devices that use these types of batteries are designed to accommodate the voltage variation. They do not necessary consume more power when the voltage is higher (new batteries) since P= V*I and the current drawn by the multimeter at any particular terminal voltage is defined by the design.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid we disagree in pointing kind of battery. The 1.65v is of NiZn type battery which, most experts say, must, if reach down at level of 1.1 v, be recharged immediately ! Otherwise we abuse it and batt. lifecycle will be only at most 35-40 times.

Comment: @Budi. No matter what type of battery it is, the battery voltage is usually specified as a nominal voltage. Be they primary or re-chargeable the battery will have a range of terminal voltage dependent on the state of charge/capacity. Your concern in the question was that the high voltage would be too much ....no you are bringing up the spent/discharged voltage. Either way, the battery should be fine in your multimeter.

Comment: So you're convinced by yourself and convince me that the multimeter will not get bad impact nor badly degraded in any way ?

Comment: @Budi. If you are not convinced, then put your batteries in a torch and run then down to 1.5 V. That should completely solve your problem.